# Referencing an element from Arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, 2d

So my Player extends Mob, which extends Entity.  In my Level class I have an arraylist and in the main Game class, I add him.

```
     public Level level;
     public Player player;

    player = new Player(level, 100, 100, input, JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Username:"));
    level.addEntity(player);
```

The problem comes in when I want to REFERENCE the players X and Y so I can plug those into my simple Slime monster AI!

I always get a NullpointerException here (line 7):

```
public void tick() {
     int xa = 0;
     int ya = 0;


    if (randomWalkTime == 0) {
        int xd = level.player.x - x;
        int yd = level.player.y - y;
        if (xd * xd + yd * yd < 50 * 50) {
            xa = 0;
            ya = 0;
            if (xd < 0) xa = -1;
            if (xd > 0) xa = +1;
            if (yd < 0) ya = -1;
            if (yd > 0) ya = +1;
        }
    }
     move(xa, ya);
     randomWalkTime++;
     tickCount++;

}
```

At the first level.player.x :(  No matter how I try to reference it.  Through game.player.x or anything else I can think of.

**Here is the main question:** There is a new "Player" that is from an arraylist in another class. How do I reference his x and y in my (Entites>Mob>) Sprite class?

If the code above isn't enough, here is the rest of the important bits:

Here is the LEVEL class where I have my entity arraylist!

```
public class Level {

private byte[] tiles;
public int width;
public int height;
public List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
private String imagePath;
private BufferedImage image;
```

The Entity class!

```
public abstract class Entity {

public int x, y;
protected Level level;

public Entity(Level level) {
    init(level);
}

public final void init(Level level) {
    this.level = level;
}


public abstract void tick();

public abstract void render(Screen screen);
```

}

The Mob Class:

```
public abstract class Mob extends Entity {

protected String name;
protected int speed;
protected int numSteps = 0;
protected boolean isMoving;
protected int movingDir = 1;
protected int scale = 1;

public Mob(Level level, String name, int x, int y, int speed) {
    super(level);
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speed = speed;
}

public void move(int xa, int ya) {
    if (xa != 0 && ya != 0) {
        move(xa, 0);
        move(0, ya);
        numSteps--;
        return;
    }
    numSteps++;
    if (!hasCollided(xa, ya)) {
        if (ya < 0)
            movingDir = 0;
        if (ya > 0)
            movingDir = 1;
        if (xa < 0)
            movingDir = 2;
        if (xa > 0)
            movingDir = 3;
        x += xa * speed;
        y += ya * speed;
    }
}

public abstract boolean hasCollided(int xa, int ya);

protected boolean isSolidTile(int xa, int ya, int x, int y) {
    if (level == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Tile lastTile = level.getTile((this.x + x) >> 3, (this.y + y) >> 3);
    Tile newTile = level.getTile((this.x + x + xa) >> 3, (this.y + y + ya) >> 3);
    if (!lastTile.equals(newTile) && newTile.isSolid()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

Here is the main part of my SLIME class!

```
public class Slime extends Mob{

int xa, ya;
private int colour = Colours.get(-1, 111, 145, 543);

private int randomWalkTime = 0;
private boolean isSwimming;
private int tickCount = 0;


public Slime(Level level, String name, int x, int y, int speed) {
    super(level, "Slime", x, y, 1);
    x = this.x;
    y = this.y;


}

public void tick() {
     int xa = 0;
     int ya = 0;


    if (randomWalkTime == 0) {
        int xd = level.player.x - x;
        int yd = level.player.y - y;
        if (xd * xd + yd * yd < 50 * 50) {
            xa = 0;
            ya = 0;
            if (xd < 0) xa = -1;
            if (xd > 0) xa = +1;
            if (yd < 0) ya = -1;
            if (yd > 0) ya = +1;
        }
    }
     move(xa, ya);
     randomWalkTime++;
     tickCount++;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `level.player.x` gives a NPE, you have two posibilities: eitehr `level` is null or `level.player` is null. You have two ways to determine which it is:

1. Preferrably, use a debugger set a breakpoint at the offending line and set a watch on these two variables.
2. Add `System.out.println()` calls to print out the values of these two variables.

Comment: level.player is returning Null!  I think this is a problem with player being an entity in an arraylist or something... I'm not sure!  Any advice now that I know that?

Comment: He just told you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @user1837518 There is no ArrayList in the code that you gave. Can you please show us how `player` is declared and initialized?